# Fibration coming from a group extension

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, group-extensions, classifying-spaces

I am trying to solve the following exercise about classifying spaces (5.1.28) in the book "Algebraic K-Theory and its applications" by Rosenberg:

Let
$$1 \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow \frac{G}{N} \longrightarrow 1$$
be a group extension. Show that there is a corresponding  fibration of classifying spaces

$$BG \longrightarrow B\left(\frac{G}{N}\right)$$

with fibre $BN$.

I know that covering maps satisfy the homotopy lifting property for fibrations and I think I was able to show that $EG \longrightarrow BG \longrightarrow B\left(\frac{G}{N}\right) $ is a covering, which then allowed me to prove that the map is a fibration. However, I do not understand how I can now identify the fibre of this fibration to be (homotopy equivalent to) $BN$. Intuitively it makes sense that this is the case, but I have problems proving it. I have not much experience with fibrations and classifying spaces, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the homotopy long exact sequence of a fibration? You could use that to show the homotopy groups of the fiber are what they need to be.

Comment: The long exact homotopy sequence will tell me that the homotopy groups of the fibre are all trivial except $\pi_1 = N$. Is that enough to conclude that the fibre has to be homotopy equivalent to $BN$? And if yes, how so?

Comment: $BN\simeq K(N,1)$ which is characterized up to homotopy equivalence by the fact that it is connected with fundamental group $N$ and all higher homotopy groups vanish.